# How to properly compose a "viewDidLoad" method

Tags: iphone, null, viewdidload, memory-management

I'm not entirely new to iPhone dev, but I ran across a situation where I was unsure about the best design choice for my code.

I have a view controller which asynchronously fetches an image from the internet and loads it into an image view. When the app receives a memory warning however, the imageView is released by didReceiveMemoryWarning. If the app receives a memory warning while loading an image, the imageView is nil by the time my code tries to load the image into the imageView.

What is the best practice for viewDidLoad? Should I just instantiate any variables that I may need later on? Or should I just check for nil values elsewhere in my code?

Also, in viewDidUnload, should I just set IBOutlet variables to nil? Why is this?

Thanks! -Matt

Comment: It's not a direct answer to this question, but perhaps you should have the download operation cancel on the memory warning as well...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create the image view on demand when the image is loaded?  No need to create it any earlier.  Or, if you do, then just have code to recreate it if it has been released.

In viewdidunload you should release resources that you created in viewdidload (or load view).  Including any IBoutlets that interface builder hooked up for you.  It's good practice to set these variables to nil to ensure they won't be inadvertently accessed after release, or double released.

Answer (score 1):

1. IBOutlets can be both instance variables and properties. In both case, we should release the references when the view, which is top most superview, is unloaded. Setting the IBOutlet retained properties to nil releases the reference automatically, but for instance variables we need to release them. We still need to set instance variables to nil because viewDidUnload is not dealloc, so we must comply with the managed memory rule or we might have invalid references sitting around inside the instance.
2. I don't think there are rules about what you should do in viewDidLoad, but if you did release and set some variables to nil in viewDidUnload, you need not have to check for nil again in the viewDidLoad unless you don't trust the framework.